# connect 4 check for win by using lists and matrix

Tags: python-3.x

I am currently writing a code that takes a connect 4 board from a text file and transfers it into a list. I split each row into a separate list and then added it to a matrix. My goal here is to check if there is a winner. I only need to check for horizontal and vertical wins. I am thinking of checking each element of the matrix to see if there is a winner for four in a row. I know that this is tedious and there is probably a more efficient way. This is what the text file contains:

```
0 0 0 0 0 0 2
0 0 0 0 0 2 1
2 1 0 2 2 1 2
2 1 0 1 1 2 2
1 1 2 2 2 1 2
1 1 1 2 1 2 1
```

I see the win in the second column but how would I check for everything to see if there is a win?
This is the code I have so far:

```
file1=open("file1.txt","r")
matrix=[]
for line in file1:
    connect=line.split(" ")
    matrix.append(connect)
print(matrix)
if matrix[0][0]==matrix[0][1]==matrix[0][2]==matrix[0][3]: #this is only temporary, supposed to check for every element
    if matrix[0][0]==1:
        print("player 1 wins!")
    elif matrix[0][0]==2:
        print("player 2 wins!")
    else:
        print("no winner")
if matrix[0][0]==matrix[1][0]==matrix[2][0]==matrix[0][0]: #check for vertical matches
    if matrix[0][0]==1:
        print("player 1 wins!")
    elif matrix[0][0]==2:
        print("player 2 wins!") 
    else:
        print("no winner")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can rely on the builtin substing match to do all of the heavy lifting.

```
# read data
board = list(
    map(
        str.split,
        """0 0 0 0 0 0 2
0 0 0 0 0 2 1
2 1 0 2 2 1 2
2 1 0 1 1 2 2
1 1 2 2 2 1 2
1 1 1 2 1 2 1""".split(
            "\n"
        ),
    )
)

# contains ['1111', '2222']
winning_strings = [c * 4 for c in "12"]


def has_winner(board):
    # get rows, e.g. rows[0] == '0000002'
    rows = map("".join, board)
    # get cols, e.g. cols[0] == '002211'
    # zip(*...) is a common idiom for a transpose
    cols = map("".join, zip(*board))
    # check if a winning sequence occurs as a substring
    # of any row or column
    return any(
        seq in row or seq in col
        for seq in winning_strings
        for row, col in zip(rows, cols)
    )


assert has_winner(board)
```